# Yii2 listview ajax

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, listview

Может кто-нибудь показать пример кода или подсказать, как в yii2 сделать  `ListView` с AJAX фильтрацией?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Вот это мы выводим во вьюхе. При клике на ссылках в контексте этого виджета (pjax) - страница будет перезагружаться частично. Таким образом Pjax помимо того, что выводит только вьюху (без теплэйта, он ещё делает pushState в браузере и там в url появляются параметры запроса. (GET запрос).

```
<?php
    $dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([ 'query' => \app\models\Flat::find() ]);
    $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = 2;
?>

<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin() ?>

<?php echo \yii\helpers\Html::beginForm('', 'get', ['data-pjax' => 1]) ?>
    <?php echo \yii\helpers\Html::input('text', 'name') ?>
    <?php echo \yii\helpers\Html::input('submit') ?>
<?php echo \yii\helpers\Html::endForm() ?>

<?php echo isset($_GET['name'])?$_GET['name']:'Нет гет запроса' ?>

<?php echo \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]) ?>

<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end() ?>
```

Обратите внимание, что если Вы хотите, чтобы форма обновляла страницу также через pjax - добавьте атрибут data-pjax к форме.